# Numpy __array_prepare__ error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to get a recipe working that I found online for doing expectation maximization (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577735-expectation-maximization/). I run into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./runem.py", line 7, in <module>
    print expectation_maximization([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[9,8,7,4,1]], 2)
  File "/local/scratch-3/dk427/rp/em.py", line 83, in expectation_maximization
    Px[o,c] = pnorm(t[o,:], params[c]['mu'], params[c]['sigma'])
  File "/local/scratch-3/dk427/rp/em.py", line 18, in pnorm
    xmt = np.matrix(x-m).transpose()
TypeError: __array_prepare__ must return an ndarray or subclass thereof which is otherwise identical to its input
```

There must be some flaw in the algorithm, or I'm giving it the wrong input, but I can't find what's going wrong. I've found that the error is caused by the subtraction `x-m`, but `x.dtype=int64` and `m.dtype=float64`, which I think should work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be passing in a list of lists rather than an array. You could do something like:

```
ts = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],[9,8,7,4,1]])
expectation_maximization(ts, 2)
```

That seems to have some problems at some point with taking a square root on my computer, but I think that might be because that data isn't good for this algorithm for some reason (but I don't know what the algorithm is trying to do, so I can't say for sure).